# Using a pipe in cloud init runcmd fails

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cloud, digital-ocean, cloud-init

How can I use a pipe to redirect the output of a command in my `runcmd` section of my cloud init script?  The following fails:

```
runcmd:
    - [curl, -sk, https://example.com/packages/current/install.bash, '|', /bin/bash, -s,  agent:certname=XYZ.com]
```

It ends up creating a script that looks like this:

```
'curl' '-sk' 'https://example.com/packages/current/install.bash' '|' '/bin/bash' '-s' 'agent:certname=XYZ.com'
```

Because the pipe becomes quoted, the script fails.  How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Have you tried something like `[sh, -c, 'curl -sk https://example.com/packages/current/install.bash | /bin/bash -s agent:certname=XYZ.com']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using an array, use a single string.

```
runcmd:
    - 'curl -sk "https://example.com/packages/current/install.bash" | /bin/bash -s,  agent:certname=XYZ.com'
```

See also:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/help-with-cloud-init-syntax-for-runcmd